# Visual Basic 2010 Overflow Error

Tags: vb.net, application-settings, integer-overflow

So I'm making a game with an infinitaly expandable length of numbers and I've gone to 2.1 Billion. This gives an overflow error.

> Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

In my code I have these two variables:

```
Dim coal As BigInteger
Dim totalCoal As BigInteger
```

And these two app settings I save them to:

[image]

```
My.Settings.coal = coal.ToString()
My.Settings.totalCoal = totalCoal.ToString()
```

I can't post more than 2 links so ill link a .rar file with the images in it.
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/s30knl44p9luhjy/Screenshots.rar?dl=0

My main concern is not being able to fix this issue as I have already distributed the application link. I need to know how to make the values unlimited in length of large numbers.

```
' Import Code
Dim data As New StreamReader("C:\Temp\Data.txt")
Dim value As String = ""
Dim dataArray(1) As String
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim setValue As Integer = 0
Do Until data.Peek = -1
    'Get 1 Value from Text File at a time
    value = data.ReadLine()
    'Place Value into Array
    dataArray(i) = value
    'Output
    saveValues.Items.Add(dataArray(i))
    'Set Values
    If setValue = 0 Then
        My.Settings.coal = saveValues.Items(0)
        setValue = 1
    ElseIf setValue = 1 Then
        My.Settings.totalCoal = saveValues.Items(1)
        setValue = 2
    End If
    i += 1
    If setValue = 2 Then
        Application.Restart()
    End If
Loop

' Export Code
saveValuesSet.Text =
My.Settings.coal & Environment.NewLine &
My.Settings.totalCoal
Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Temp\Data.txt")
    writer.WriteLine(saveValuesSet.Text)
End Using
```

Comment: You store a `String` to an `Integer`. This compiles because you did not put `Option Strict On` at the beginning of the module. Please do, then it will not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 billion is the maximum value for the `Integer` data type, you can use `Long` instead to allow you to go up to about 9 * 10^18.

If you want to use numbers that can be of any size at all, you should look at [System.Numerics.BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You will need to add a reference to System.Numerics to your project in order to use BigInteger.

If you want to store a BigInteger in Settings, you could create a Setting with type String and store the string representation there (of course the String could be extremely long).

```
My.Settings.BigIntegerString = myBigInteger.ToString
```

Comment: If you looked at the screenshots the OP provided, you'd see they are already using `BigInteger`.

Comment: I didn't want to download the .rar file. I see it now that you have edited the question. The problem (apart from the one you pointed out) appears to be that the OP is trying to store a BigInteger in an Integer Settings item.

Comment: So what could i do to fix this cause everyone is bugging me to fix it as they can't play. Should i change the settings from integer to string and it will work?

Comment: @SelectGamer: Did you try changing the type of your Settings items from Integer to String as I suggested in the final part of my answer? Note that if you do that you will need to use BigInteger.Parse on the string when you want to read from the Settings item.

Comment: @Blackwood the only thing i did change is in settings integer to string and it seems to be working. ill post my export and import code in the question details for you to see.

Comment: @Blackwood i posted it and tried to make it a code block but it didn't work. you think you can do it?

Comment: @SelectGamer: I have edited to question to format the code (the edit will have to be reviewed before it will show). Is everything working now, or do you still have a question?

Comment: Any particular reason you chose `BigInteger` over `Decimal`?

Comment: actually i use decimal for a couple values in my settings. there are 85 values in my settings. Everything seems to be working. No Overflow error but i will leave this question open just in case it comes back so please don't hesitate to check back. I could also just comment or message you. I'll mark you answer and thank you.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin: Not sure if your question is directed at me or the OP. I mentioned BigInteger because the question asks for "infinitely expandable" numbers. Decimal can hold about 28 digits, which ought to be enough for all practical purposes, but is a lot short of "infinite".